# AppStore API for In-App purchase data

Tags: ios, app-store

Is there any way I can request `App Store` in-app purchase data for **my** iOS Application? The reason behind this is that content is added through a backend server and we'd like to avoid having to fill duplicate content rather than pulling it directly from the AppStore.

I.e: when we create a new in-app purchase content in **iTunes Connect**, we have to assign a **product ID**, **Reference Name** and a **Price tier**. We have to add the same data to our backend server, but we'd like to add only the **product ID** and pull the rest from the `App Store` through an API.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you find it? I am also looking for a server-side Price API, which can be called from our server.

Comment: Have you implemented this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

1) At a minimum you have to have the productId.

2) Then you can create a:

```
SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers]; //a set of id's
productsRequest.delegate = self;  //use SKProductsRequestDelegate
[productsRequest start];
```

3) This will return to you a `SKProductsResponse` of which contains a `products` property, which is an array of `SKProducts`

4) From an `SKProduct` you can then have access to:

```
localizedDescription
localizedTitle
price
priceLocale
productIdentifier
```

[SKProduct Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProduct_Reference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKProduct)

Additionally, it looks like someone has been able to tap into the iTunes Connect API.  But I don't see anything about IAP's [in this example response](https://github.com/fastlane/itc-api-docs/blob/master/examples/details.md).  Check out [Fastlane on Github.](https://github.com/fastlane/itc-api-docs)

Comment: Hmm, I think I didn't explain myself right. I need exactly this, but for server-side code, like maybe a JSON API or a PHP/JS SDK

Comment: Any luck finding that?

Comment: @YogeshKaushik Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No, there is no server side API for Price.

Comment: @YogeshKaushik are you implement alternative method or find solution for this ?

Comment: Lookup for Transporter tool, that might help. I tried few other mech as well, like getting price from client etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no available API from Apple to fetch this info from Server. There is a way though - you can use Transporter which is Apples' java based command-line tool.

https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/en.lproj/static.html